# I want to transfer my additional css code to my theme file--?

Tags: css

What should i do? I added a css style code my custom header.  Now i want ti give my theme to my fruend. Now, can additional css keep in theme file?

Comment: Easiest way is to copy the css out of the additional css section. Put it through a css beautifier, paste it into notepad, save as a css file and send both the theme and the css to paste in once his copy is up. The logical thing to have done is set up the theme as a child and created a css file with your additional css inside, then called that into your header.php file within the head section.

Answer (score 0):

If you already had a theme, and you have just added some CSS, what you'll need to do is create a child theme. The child theme will hold a short comment that tells WordPress to reference the parent theme (the original theme you were using), and then it can contain all your custom styles. This way, you and your friend can both use the original parent theme and whenever it's updated you will not lose any of your additions.

If you didn't already have a theme, and you have created a full theme including CSS, all you need to do is .zip the files and send the zip to your friend. The friend can then install the theme directly from that zip file.